# Multiple tables or multiple dbs in Android app?

Tags: android, database

I am writing an Android storytelling app to create and edit stories with texts, pictures, sounds etc. So far I have one story, one database, one table, and everything works fine. Now I will move to multiple stories and I am thinking of whether to keep a single database with one table per story, or having multiple databases, or a combination of the two (like 10 tables per database). I will need to up/download stories to/from a storage service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think the main problem is your basic database scheme. I can't imagine that the table you have created for one story can't be normalized into separate tables.

So create a table for a story containing the story title, for example. Than a table for texts and sounds and everything else you need. Each of these tables will have a foreign key so that they can be referenced to the story they belong to.

That should also solve the problem of thinking about separate databases or tables for a story.

Also keep in mind that you have to deal with database scheme changes on every database when you decide to have a single database for each story. Might be a mess and complicated when you have to update 10 different databases just because you added one column to the table...

Answer (score 0):

I would separate it into different databases. I think it will be much easier to develop. For example the version in the onUpdate() function has to increase with each change in the database-scheme. If you have one big database the version will increase fast(er).

- It will be easier to separate the
  code in logical files, as you can
  extend the SQLiteOpenHelper()
  function for each Database (divide
  and conquer).
- You could simply close an database
  when switching between the games. And
  open the other database.
- If you have a major change in one
  database you might want to download
  the database from an server instead
  of coding everything, if you have
  separate databases you will save
  bandwidth.
- If you decide to download the
  databases during runtime, every
  database has it's own
  SQLiteOpenHelper with the download
  information needed.
- Depending on the size of the database
  (the amount of games) it could be
  faster to search in separate
  databases.

But I'm no guru, there might be good reasons against this design decisions.

Comment: Thanks Warren and Darokthar. At this moment I am inclined to follow Warren's suggestion (separate tables in the same db), with all data for a story in one table for easy import / export.